# Good opensource OCR in C#

Tags: c#, ocr

Is there a good open source OCR implementation in C#? I am trying to solve the following problem. I have a document which contains boxes and people enter their id number in the box. Now I want to figure out the id number in program.

Thank you,
Bala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) based on great [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) ocr engine.

*The Tesseract OCR engine was one of the top 3 engines in the 1995 UNLV Accuracy test. Between 1995 and 2006 it had little work done on it, but it is probably one of the most accurate open source OCR engines available.*

Comment: I tried tesseract but it can identify characters in some font but not hand written text. Have you tried it to recognize hand written text.

Comment: hand writing is not OCR it is ICR. It's a different thing.

Comment: tesseract bad library and does not support multithreading